# Not able to get raw folder files after language change in the application for Android 8 devices

Tags: android

I am working on an application which supports 2 languages English and German. I'm loading some html files from raw folder to display it in webview. For that I've created 2 raw folders namely "raw" and "raw-de". It properly loads html from respective raw folders when language is changed on Pre-Oreo devices but it's not working on Oreo. Below is the code to load html file from raw folder.

```
txt_desc.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/what_is_ergo.html");
```

I'm not able to figure out how to make it work on Android 8.0. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try reading raw file like this:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
val inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.what_is_ergo);

while (it.read(buffer) != -1) {
   builder.append(String(buffer));
}

txt_desc.loadDataWithBaseURL("", builder.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: Your code works but instead of `txt_desc.loadUrl(builder.toString())` we need to use `txt_desc.loadDataWithBaseURL("", builder.toString(), "text/html", "UTF-8", "");`